# string value of byte array - and back again to byte array

Tags: go

I am trying to benchmark some Decoding code. I have printed the encoding byte array, so I can hardcode it in the test file, to separate out the Encode part.

Therefore I have fmt.Println() a byte array

```
buf := bytes.Buffer{}
enc := gob.NewEncoder(&buf)
err := enc.Encode(<my struct>)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
byteQuads := buf.Bytes()
buf.Reset()
fmt.Println(byteQuads) // << [77 255 129 3 1 1 7 82...]
// or
fmt.Println(string(byteQuads[:])) // << M��...
```

Question: How can read this hardcode into a byte array([]byte) again

```
b := []byte(???) // [77 255 129 3 1 1 7 82...] or M��
gob.NewDecoder(bytes.NewReader(b))
```

Comment: You can pass `byteQuads`, assuming the encoded result can be decoded as is.

Comment: Right, but I want to separate encoding and decoding into two different tests.

Comment: Oh so you want to hardcode the encoded result. You can use slice literal. Should I show it in answer?

Comment: Thanks @JakubDóka I want to hardcode "[77 255 129 3 1 1 7 82...] or M��" and then use it in a test reading it in using something like []byte(???).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to create a [composite literal](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Composite_literals) with the test data, then use the `%#v` format verb in fmt.Printf:

```
buf := bytes.Buffer{}
enc := gob.NewEncoder(&buf)
err := enc.Encode()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Printf("var testData = %#v\n", buf.Bytes())  
// prints var testData = []byte{0x1f, 0xff, …
```

This code prints a line of text that you can paste directly into a Go source file.

If your goal is to reuse the encoded data over and over, then do the following:

```
buf := bytes.Buffer{}
enc := gob.NewEncoder(&buf)
err := enc.Encode(<my struct>)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
b := buf.Bytes() // reuse this slice of bytes to create decoders.

⋮

dec := gob.NewDecoder(bytes.NewReader(b))
// do something with the decoder

⋮

// create another decoder on the same data.
dec = gob.NewDecoder(bytes.NewReader(b))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use constructor syntax with slices. Lets show an example:

```golang
array := []int{1, 2, 3}
```

Equivalent in python is:

```
array = [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Thanks, note that fmt.Println prints in this format: [77 255 129 3 1 1 7 82...]

Comment: If you use special formatting (forgot which), you can display it as written in code.